# Type error while using re.match

Tags: python, scrapy, typeerror

I called re.match but the error indicates that the list requires an integer not a string.

```
tripadvisor_item['avg_stars'] = re.match(r'(\S+)', snode_restaurant_item_avg
_stars).group()
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Here's the code,

```
# Build item index.
for snode_restaurant in snode_restaurants:
    # Cleaning string and taking only the first part before whitespace.
    snode_restaurant_item_avg_stars = clean_parsed_string(get_parsed_string(snode_restaurant, 'div[@class="wrap"]/div[@class="entry wrap"]/div[@class="description"]/div[@class="wrap"]/div[@class="rs rating"]/span[starts-with(@class, "rate")]/img[@class="sprite-ratings"]/@alt'))
    tripadvisor_item['avg_stars'] = re.match(r'(\S+)', snode_restaurant_item_avg_stars).group()*

    # Popolate reviews and address for current item.
    yield Request(url=tripadvisor_item['url'], meta={'tripadvisor_item': tripadvisor_item}, callback=self.parse_fetch_review)
```

Even in the docs it says that,

```
"""Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found."""
```

Comment: What's the value of `snode_restaurant_item_avg_stars` ?

Comment: `tripadvisor_item` is a list ?

Comment: It is a string, as in I have a method that is called which will clean the Xpath string returned by scrapy. Yes `tripadvisor_item` is a [list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is to do with `tripadvisor_item` having `avg_stars` as one of the `indices` (Because `tripadvisor_item` is not previously defined, Python could think you are referencing `[]`).

```
tripadvisor_item['avg_stars'] = re.match(r'(\S+)', snode_restaurant_item_avg_stars).group()*
```

Try declaring `tripadvisor_item` as a map, so it can be used as a [`KEYVALUEPAIR`](https://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/python-tutorial-dictionaries-key-value-pair-maps-basics/)

```
tripadvisor_item = {}
# do the rest of your code here ...
```